# Choose a random number from a number that is closest to a number

Tags: calculus

Good morning,

I want to create a procedural generation software and in it, we will be able to choose the minimum length of the lakes, the maximum length of the lakes and the average length.
So I'd like to know how to get a number that's as close as possible to one but that can vary between two limits.

(If possible have the code in C#)

Comment: So it has to be random, right? What kind of a distribution do you want for the random variable? Uniform? Normal? Something else?

Comment: How about $$1+{1\over m}-{1\over n}$$ where $m,n$ are very large?

Comment: Please engage with the comments, Tartala.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP has abandoned it.